# Why BeautifulSoup returning same information over and over again

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

When I am trying to scrap website over multiple pages `BeautifulSoup` returning the 1st page content for all the page range.. It is getting repeated again and again..

```
data=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,10):
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
  url="https://www.collegesearch.in/engineering-colleges-india".format(i)

  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
    
  #clg url and name
  clg=soup.find_all('h2', class_='media-heading mg-0')

   #other details
  details=soup.find_all('dl', class_='dl-horizontal mg-0')

  _dict={'clg':clg,'details':details}

  df=pd.DataFrame(_dict)

  data=data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: "url" is the same in each iteration, it doesn't contain the number from "i".

Comment: Thank you so much..!! i was doing iteration using format , but it was not working , but the changes you have suggested worked for me..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue of `BeautifulSoup` - Check your loop, you never change the page, cause url is always the same:

```
https://www.collegesearch.in/engineering-colleges-india
```

So change your code and set your counter as value of page parameter:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    url=f"https://www.collegesearch.in/engineering-colleges-india?page={i}"
    print(url)
```

May also take a short read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html